# Macro to refer to struct member, homegrown complex type to standard C99 complex conversion

Tags: c, unix, struct, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I'm reworking the innards of a *large* scientific application, written in C, so that the homegrown `MyComplex` type and its associated routines are replaced with arithmetic that's using the C99 `complex` type.

Some of it is easy, like

```
#ifdef HAVE_COMPLEX_H
#include <complex.h>
#define double complex MyComplex
#define ComplexAddition(a, b) ((a) + (b))
#define ComplexConjugation(a) (conj(a))
#else
/* very old code, used everywhere in the project */
struct MyComplex { double re, double im };
typedef struct MyComplex MyComplex;
MyComplex ComplexAddition(MyComplex a, MyComplex b) { ... }
MyComplex ComplexConjugation(MyComplex a) { ... }
#endif
```

That bit works, and I'm happy with it, but some routines peek inside the `MyComplex` struct, so I thought I was being clever and replaced every occurrence of `c.re` with `RealPart(c)` where

```
#ifdef HAVE_COMPLEX_H
#define RealPart(c) creal(c)
#else
#define RealPart(c) c ## .re
#endif
```

(and analogous for `ImagPart(c)` and the `im` member).

This works splendidly if `HAVE_COMPLEX_H` is defined, but if I try to compile with `HAVE_COMPLEX_H` unset, the Clang compiler on my Mac (clang 7.3.0) says:

```
utils.c:13505:9: error: pasting formed '].', an invalid preprocessing token
        RealPart(m[row][dim - 1]), ImagPart(m[row][dim - 1]));
        ^
./utils.h:39:23: note: expanded from macro 'RealPart'
#define RealPart(c) c ## .re
                      ^
utils.c:13505:36: error: pasting formed '].', an invalid preprocessing token
        RealPart(m[row][dim - 1]), ImagPart(m[row][dim - 1]));
                                   ^
./utils.h:40:23: note: expanded from macro 'ImagPart'
#define ImagPart(c) c ## .im
                      ^
```

Similarly, the GNU 4.2.1 compiler (on OpenBSD) says

```
utils.c:9968:1: error: pasting "sum" and "." does not give a valid preprocessing token
utils.c:9968:1: error: pasting "sum" and "." does not give a valid preprocessing token
utils.c:10059:1: error: pasting "]" and "." does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

I can't seem to get the macro definition correct, and I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to create a macro that expands to a member of a struct.

It's probably something simple that I have overlooked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `##` concatenates string, and the arguments to `RealPart()` and `ImagPart()` aren't strings.

The correct macro definitions (for when `HAVE_COMPLEX_H` is not defined) are

```
#define RealPart(c) c.re
#define ImagPart(c) c.im
```

It was a bit too obvious for me.